Vite Proxy cause Infinite Request Loop
What I want to do is change this URL (query parameters only):
http://localhost:5173/externesysteme/google?code=123&scope=456&state=789
to
http://localhost:5173/externesysteme/google?codeExt=123&scopeExt=456&stateExt=789
The reason I want to change the parameters is that Keycloak is expecting these three parameters to perform its functions. However, I receive these three parameters from another API, which is why I want to modify these parameters through a proxy. This is the only way we can achieve it.
When I set up a Vite proxy, it causes an infinite redirect loop due to the same URL.
I setup a proxy in vite.config.js. Now the Problem what i have is, that i get an Infinite Loop on Incoming Requests in the Server until the Server breaks, when i redirect to the same URL only with other Query Parameteres.
Here is my Proxy Setup:
server: {
    proxy: {
      "/externesysteme/google": {
        target: "http://localhost:5173",
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          proxy.on("proxyReq", (proxyReq, req, res) => {
            let url = new URL(req.url, "http://localhost:5173");
            const searchParams = url.searchParams;

            let paramsChanged = false;

            // Überprüfe und ändere die Query-Parameter
            if (searchParams.has("code")) {
              const value = searchParams.get("code");
              searchParams.delete("code");
              searchParams.append("codeExt", value);
              paramsChanged = true;
            }

            if (searchParams.has("scope")) {
              const value = searchParams.get("scope");
              searchParams.delete("scope");
              searchParams.append("scopeExt", value);
              paramsChanged = true;
            }

            if (searchParams.has("state")) {
              const value = searchParams.get("state");
              searchParams.delete("state");
              searchParams.append("stateExt", value);
              paramsChanged = true;
            }

            if (paramsChanged) {
              const newLocation = url.pathname + "?" + searchParams.toString();

              res.writeHead(301, {
                Location: newLocation,
                "x-rewritten-url": "true",
              });
              console.log("Redirecting to:", newLocation);
              res.end();
            }
          });
        },
      },
    },
  },

This is the NGINX Config where it Works. I dont need NGINX anymore, so i need to do it with ViteJS.
location /externesysteme/datev {
        if ($args ~ ^(.+&|)code(=.*)$) {
            return 301 "$uri?$1codeExt$2";
        }
        if ($args ~ ^(.+&|)state(=.*)$) {
            return 301 "$uri?$1stateExt$2";
        }
        if ($args ~ ^(.+&|)scope(=.*)$) {
            return 301 "$uri?$1scopeExt$2";
        }
    }


Your proxy listens to http://localhost:5173 and you are redirecting requests to the same address!? Isn't it an infinite loop? You need to redirect requests to the Keycloak service address.

By the way, you can do the exact job using Nginx only and rename query parameters using the reverse proxy rule definition.
